# "Ihr" anstatt "Sie"

Tags: personal-pronoun

Ich habe schon viele Videospiele auf Deutsch gespielt, und sie benutzen fast jedes Mal "Ihr" anstatt "Sie", wenn sie auf den Spieler (nicht Plural) hinweisen. z.B. "Ihr seid besiegt" statt "Sie sind besiegt".

Ich weiß dass diese Verwendung in Altdeutsch war. Ist das auch hier so? Danke!

Comment: Könntest du bitte ein paar Beispiele für solche Spiele nennen? Das könnte eine relevante Kontextinformation sein.

Comment: Wenn du Mitglied eines Teams bist, ist *Ihr* (2.Pers. Plural) richtig.

Comment: Ohne Beispiele mit Kontext wird das Raterei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es geht dabei um die [Höflichkeitsform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform).
(Anrede in der 2. Person Plural (Ihr))
Hierbei werden Personen die besonderen Respekt verdienen anders angesprochen.

Wie in diesen Beispielen von Wikipedia:

„Habt Ihr den Wechsel erhalten, gnädiger Herr?“ 
(Anrede an einen gehobenen Bürgerlichen oder niederen Adel: 2. Person Plural, auch im weiteren Gespräch)
„Haben Euer Gnaden wohl geruht?“ 
(„Euer“ in der 2. Person Plural, das Verb jedoch in der 3. Person Plural; auch die Fortsetzung in Rede oder Brief geschieht hier in der 3. Person Plural)

Ich gehe davon aus, dass du in deinen Computerspielen eine Art Herrscher bist und deshalb mit dieser Höflichkeitsform angeredet wirst.

Answer (score 5):

Übersetzungen folgen immer mehreren Aspekten. Darunter:

- was steht im Original?
- was drückt das Original damit aus? (historisch, Kontext, etc)
- was will ich damit ausdrücken?
- was erwartet der Leser/Spieler

Wie schon von SerenaT geschrieben handelt es sich beim *Ihr* um eine Höflichkeitsform. Das sogenannte Ihrzen hat dabei einen ziemlichen Wandel im Laufe der Geschichte durchgemacht. War es im Althochdeutsch-Mittelhochdeutsch die Standardform für die höfliche Anrede wurden daraus im 14. Jhd. Anreden wie "mein Herr oder "meine Dame", etc.

Mitte des 17. Jahrhundert  verschwanden diese Formulierungen, das Ihr blieb allerdings erhalten galt aber nicht mehr so respektvoll wie die 3. Pers Singular (er/sie)

Im 18. Jahrhundert erscheint angelehnt an den Plural Majestatix die 3. Person Plural "Sie". Diese steht über dem er.

Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts sinkt die Respektbedeutung des "er/sie" und steht nun zwischen *du* und *ihr*. Die Verwendung der 3. Person Plural steht allerdings weiterhin an erster Stelle.

([Quelle](https://coramaysregency.wordpress.com/schreibstube/historische-anrede-sie-du-oder-ihr/) die übrigens auch so lesenswert ist)

---

Heute haben wir, abgesehen von einigen Regionen, eigentlich nur noch zwei Formen. Das *du* und das *sie*. Andere Formen oder Konstruktionen klingen in unseren Ohren altbacken, ungewöhnlich oder historisch.

Übersetzt man nun einen Text (oder Spiel) kann man auf verschiedene Aspekte achten. Die Zeit in der es spielt, die Beziehung der Personen, etc. In den Scheibenweltromanen wählte der Übersetzer etwa, dass sämtliche Personen sich duzen. Der Kommandant der Wache zum Patrizier also Sachen sagte wie: "Ja Herr, aber weißt du ...". In den letzten Romanen wechselte der (neue) Übersetzer dann in die Sie-Form (was zu einiger Kritik führte).

Was Spiele angeht die ein gewisses Mittelalter-Feeling aufweisen wird so gut wie immer auf die Ihr-Form zurückgegriffen. Siehe diesen [Questtext](https://de.wowhead.com/quest=28734/ein-gefallen-f%C3%BCr-melithar) von World of Warcraft.

> Ihr solltet mit Melithar sprechen. Ich glaube, er hatte bereits einige Probleme mit den Grells.
>
> Ich schätze, er kann Euch Platz anbieten, an dem Ihr einiges von Eurem Hab und Gut verstauen könnt, falls Ihr ihm helft.

Um zu einem Abschluss zu kommen möchte ich aus ["Übersetzen von Videospieltexten: Nekrotexte lesen und übersetzen" von Changgun Kim](https://books.google.de/books?id=OlOGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=anrede%20ihr%20videospiel&source=bl&ots=8uTAU6Rcsn&sig=ACfU3U2-cgX4svubB9U-mg6FMCXdNKs1eA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisw5Wj54jiAhWCsKQKHS41BjgQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=anrede%20ihr%20videospiel&f=false) zitieren der das ganze wahrscheinlich ganz gut zusammenfasst

> Inner- und außerhalb des Videospiels variieren Anreden für Gamer. Im Videospiel sind die Gamer, die mit ihrem Avatar identifiziert sind, Daevas, von Einwohnern in Atreia verehrte Wesen. Deshalb wird als Anrede für die Gamer nicht nur im koreanischen "Du", sondern "Ihr", ... verwendet.

Es kommt also immer ganz drauf an, was das (zeitliche) Setting ist und was für eine Art von Charakter man dort spielt.